# How to create routes for an OpenVPN tunnel?

Tags: linux, windows, routing, openvpn, google-cloud-platform

I have three instances created in google cloud platform, one of them hosts a linux system and the other a windows 2012 r2 server, I have already created the vpn tunnel between my client and my linux instance, the question here is what is it I have to do to be able to connect via RDP to my windows servers, the ip addresses of the instances are as follows:

Instance with OpenVpn installed:

```
Internal network interface, eth0: 10.128.0.3
Openvpn interface, tun0 10.8.0.1
Ip publishes 104.154.145.xxx
```

Windows server instance:

```
Internal network interface, eth0: 10.128.0.2
Ip publishes 35.184.137.xxx
```

Windows server instance:

```
Internal network interface, eth0: 10.128.0.3
Ip publishes 35.184.137.xxx
```

When I connect as a client, the OpenVpn service gives me ip: `10.8.0.6`.

I'd like to connect to the Windows servers by RDP.

I believe it is related to some routing issue but I'm not sure, can you please assist?

Comment: Have you tried using SSH tunnelling? That would be the most simple way to do this.

Comment: For ssh I already have it, the tunnel vpn is ready and I can connect through it, what happens is that our databases and web services are hosted on windows servers, then you want to occupy that vpn to access those servers , I used linux for this for money reasons, I hope I have explained

Answer (score 1):

I read all communications with **Itai**. Along with configuring routing in `OpenVPN` configuration file and Windows machine, you should enable forwarding on your Linux machine, to enable it, just add `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and execute `sysctl -p`. After this you should add `iptables` rule by command `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`. It should be enough.

Don't forget to save iptables configuration by command `service iptables save`.

Comment: The iptables command does not work on linux, try it but it marks it as unknown, I'm using debian jessie, ip forwarding is active

Comment: @JonathanRiveraDiaz please share `iptables-save` output.

Comment: iptables: unrecognized service,That's the way out

Comment: @JonathanRiveraDiaz looks like you don't have `iptables`. Try to install as mentioned in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818931/debian-8-iptables-persistent

Comment: apt install iptables-persistent
Reading package lists... Done
iptables-persistent is already the newest version.
root@debian-vpn:/home/ing_jonathan_rivera_diaz# service iptables-persistent status
● iptables-persistent.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
root@debian-vpn:/home/ing_jonathan_rivera_diaz# service iptables-persistent start
Failed to start iptables-persistent.service: Unit iptables-persistent.service failed to load:
 No such file or directory.

Comment: @JonathanRiveraDiaz `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -y iptables-persistent`

Comment: Still not working, mark me the following:
Bash: iptables-persistent: command not found

Can not create rule with ufw?

Comment: @JonathanRiveraDiaz `iptables` starts by command `invoke-rc.d netfilter-persistent`. After this all iptables command should work.

Comment: Then the route that you gave me, the one of the route, I put it of the following way?

Invoke-rc.d netfilter-persistent iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58867/discussion-between-alexander-t-and-jonathan-rivera-diaz).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add routes.

On OpenVPN server, edit your `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` and add:

```
push "route 10.128.0.0 255.255.240.0"
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Then restart OpenVPN service.

Add the following route on your Windows machines, run:

```
route add 10.8.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.128.0.3 -p
```

And test it.

Also, check out [this article](http://www.geek-kb.com/install-and-configure-openvpn-centos-6-x/), it covers the whole routing issue in relation to OpenVPN.

**Edit:**
In order to test it, try running "ping 10.128.0.2" from the your vpn client machine.

Comment: The net mask defines the size of your network... it's probably 255.255.255.0 so I guess you don't need to change it, just add the "push route" lines to your openvpn server configuration and restart the service and add the routes I showed and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, my question is, do I have to delete the route that you mentioned in the first response?

Comment: You can but it's not a must... you can run the same command you used to add it, just replace the word "add" with "del" and run the command again.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it and let you know what happens

Comment: Edited my answer to show you how to test it. Also, please delete some older comments from the answer, thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to ping the address 10.128.0.2, but I can not ping, on my client I have the ip 10.8.0.6, add everything as you told me but it does not work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58815/discussion-between-itai-ganot-and-jonathan-rivera-diaz).